# Proving a divisible statement by contradiction

Tags: analysis

How do I show that Q(n): "4n+1 is divisible by 3" where n∈ N is a false statement for all n.

I was thinking of showing that this statement is false because the base case does not work for n = 1. However, I am asked to prove it by contradiction.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: If eg. $n=2$, then $4n{+}1$ is divisible by $3$.So you need to be a little more careful with your quantifiers ("for all")

Comment: Or just the order: "...for all n is a false statement".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can say, by contradiction:

If $4n+1$ is divisible by $3$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then for any natural $n$ there exists a natural $k$ such that $4n+1=3k$ which means that $k = \dfrac{4n+1}{3}$ is a natural number for any $n$, which is false because for $n=1$ we have $k=\dfrac{5}{3}$ which is not a natural number.

Hope this can help

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you very much!